# Remote access dialog doesn't show users

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-7, domain-controller

I am trying to set up remote access for her but the computer doesn't have any local users and the computer has nothing except for the computer in the places dialog box when I go to add users to the remote desktop list.

I just got a job as an intern system admin at a company and I had to setup a computer for remote access for another employee. She is able to log into the computer physically with her domain username/password and she has access to the internet. Her computer is connected through a switch to the router and the ADC is connected through a switch to the router. There is another computer on the same switch as hers but that computer is able to find users in the domain and it is connected to the domain.

When I go into the firewall settings, it says that her computer is connected to a Work network but not to the domain. I can see her user and her computer listed in the Active Directory Computers and Users window. The computer has two network interfaces, an ethernet card and a wireless card. Even when it's connected to the internet with the ethernet card, the name of the network, which should be the name of the domain is stuck as the SSID of one of the wifi networks around the office. The computer can ping the ADC fine. The ADC is running Windows Server 2008 R2 and her computer is running Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.

Comment: Please consider writing your question and subject more like newspaper style (inverted pyramid).  Your subject and first sentence/paragraph, should tell me what the problem is.  Then you should add additional supporting detail.  If you want help, it is important to tell people what you want help with, and not have them waste their first impression being that you are talking about your career.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I'd do is compare the DNS settings between the computer that correctly enumerates the list of Domain users and groups with the computer that does not. It's very important that computers joined to an Active Directory Domain use DNS servers that have the right zone information for the Domain.

Have a look at the misbehaving computer's Event Log, too. You shouldn't be seeing error or warnings, for the most part, on a well-behaved Windows 7 client.